# How to prevent data submission after refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && $_POST['Submit'])
```

I'm trying to avoid the double data submission on the form when the page refreshed/reload it submitted the same row in my database.

I searched a lot and find many solutions like using GET instead of POST, but it doesn't work for me.

I used server side validation(wrote all validation code under above written code) in this form & submission take place on the same page.

please get me out of this error. Thank You!

Comment: use a header / sessions, tokens

Comment: How can I use session for the same page? @Fred-ii-

Comment: you check if they're set